# Save QPainter after called update

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to draw straight lines on qml , but every time I draw a line, the previous disappears, I wonder if it has any thing to do with the update method, any ways to solve this problem.

**main.qml**

```
MouseArea{
    id:fidpoint
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressed: {
        switch(addstate.currentText){
        case 'Track':
            map.setTstart(mouseX,mouseY);
            draw_line.setColor("black");
            draw_line.setStart(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY));
            draw_line.setEnd(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY));
            draw_line.update();
            break;
        }
    }
    onReleased: {
        switch(addstate.currentText){
        case 'Track':
            map.addTrack(mouseX,mouseY);
            draw_line.setColor("black");
            draw_line.setEnd(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY));
            draw_line.update();
            break;
        }
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        switch(addstate.currentText){
        case 'Track':
            draw_line.setColor("black");
            draw_line.setEnd(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY));
            draw_line.update();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

draw_line is the Object's id that I registered to qml from main.cpp

**paint.cpp**

```
void Paint::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen(m_color, 2);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
    painter->drawLine(startNode,endNode);
}
```

paint is the class that inherits from `QQuickPaintedItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible option would be to create an image and save the changes there, but this would solve your problem in the short term. A better option is that draw_line draw only one line, then add it as a child of the item you want the canvas to be.

**lineitem.h**

```
#ifndef LINEITEM_H
#define LINEITEM_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>

class LineItem: public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QPoint startPos READ startPos WRITE setStartPos NOTIFY startPosChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QPoint endPos READ endPos WRITE setEndPos NOTIFY endPosChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor lineColor READ lineColor WRITE setLineColor NOTIFY lineColorChanged)
public:
    using QQuickPaintedItem::QQuickPaintedItem;
    void paint(QPainter *painter);

    QPoint startPos() const;
    void setStartPos(const QPoint &startPos);
    QPoint endPos() const;
    void setEndPos(const QPoint &endPos);
    QColor lineColor() const;
    void setLineColor(const QColor &lineColor);

signals:
    void startPosChanged();
    void endPosChanged();
    void lineColorChanged();

private:
    QPoint m_startPos;
    QPoint m_endPos;
    QColor m_lineColor;
};

#endif // LINEITEM_H
```

**lineitem.cpp**

```
#include "lineitem.h"

#include <QPainter>

void LineItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    QPen pen(m_lineColor, 2);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawLine(m_startPos, m_endPos);
}

QPoint LineItem::startPos() const
{
    return m_startPos;
}

void LineItem::setStartPos(const QPoint &startPos)
{
    if(m_startPos == startPos)
        return;
    m_startPos = startPos;
    emit startPosChanged();
    update();
}

QPoint LineItem::endPos() const
{
    return m_endPos;
}

void LineItem::setEndPos(const QPoint &endPos)
{
    if(m_endPos == endPos)
        return;
    m_endPos = endPos;
    emit endPosChanged();
    update();
}

QColor LineItem::lineColor() const
{
    return m_lineColor;
}

void LineItem::setLineColor(const QColor &lineColor)
{
    if(m_lineColor == lineColor)
        return;
    m_lineColor = lineColor;
    emit lineColorChanged();
    update();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import com.eyllanesc.org 1.0

Window {
    id: win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property LineItem currentItem: null

    Rectangle{
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPressed: {
                currentItem = create_lineitem(canvas)
                currentItem.lineColor = "green"
                currentItem.anchors.fill = canvas
                currentItem.startPos = Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)
                currentItem.endPos = Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)
            }
            onReleased:  currentItem.endPos = Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)
            onPositionChanged: currentItem.endPos = Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)
        }
    }

    function create_lineitem(parentItem, color) {
        return Qt.createQmlObject('import com.eyllanesc.org 1.0; LineItem{}',
                                           parentItem);
    }

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "lineitem.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<LineItem>("com.eyllanesc.org", 1, 0, "LineItem");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51145763).

Comment: @Changlin 
What version of Qt do you use? An Item has a painting space, this is not unlimited, with anchors.fill = stable parent that the item occupies all the space of the father. Have you downloaded my code, have you modified it?

Comment: @Changlin 
I have updated the example, try it back and tell me if you have problems, I recommend downloading the files.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Just another question to ask, if I got several sets of start and end points, how can I call the LineItem class to draw the points out?